# Как сделать блок с заголовком посередине с помощью CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, grid

Есть заголовок, как на картинке, он занимает 2 строки. Из-за переноса на вторую строку, справа остается много пустого пространства, что выглядит, как будто заголовок выравнен по левому краю, хотя настроено выравнивание по центру (выравнивание делалось через **justify-item** css grid, а не через **text-align:center**).

Дело в том, что при переносе на вторую строку, заголовок резервирует всю длину первой строки в блоке.

Как сделать так, чтобы при переносе заголовка на вторую строку, первая строка стала занимать место по крайнему слову в строке, а сам заголовок отцентрировался относительно пустого пространства по центру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.article {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 970px;
    place-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 750px);
    place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Заголовок первого уровня Заголовок первого уровня Заголовок первого уровня</h1>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Покажите текущий CSS блока

Comment: По-моему, никак этого не сделать...

Comment: добавил css, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: С учётом того, что такого способа выравнивания, как вам хочется, в CSS не существует... у вас помимо ниже предложенного разделения текста. есть ещё два варианта: 1. существует тег <wbr> 2. существуют javascript и jQuery расширения для расстановки переносов.

Answer (score 0):

Оберни нужный текст в `<span>` и задай ему такой же класс как в `h1`, и второй класс для того что бы прописать такой же font size, text-align center.

Comment: Пример кода смотрелся бы очень уместно. Добавьте, пожалуйста, некоторый образец для наглядности.

Comment: Покажи. Скорее всего не получится. Или ты предлагаешь явно делить текст на строки?

Comment: забыл сразу css загрузить. сейчас загрузил, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что не понятно в моем ответе? Не работает?

Answer (score 0):

justify-content - переносит по центру блочные элементы и h1 как раз он центрует как блок, но когда появляется две строки, он расширяется на 100%, так как первая строка по сути занимает всё пространство. а текст как мы знаем не является блочным и находится как раз внутри .content, и всё также центрируется благодаря text-align: center;

```css
.article {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 970px;
    place-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #dadada;
}

.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(320px, 750px);
    place-items: center;
}
.content h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Заголовок первого уровня Заголовок первого уровня Заголовок первого уровня</h1>
    </div>
</article>
```